# Display search result in another page

Tags: php, ionic-framework

Here is my api code for search data by pin code:

```
function findPlace(){
    $request = \Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();
    $pinCode = json_decode($request->getBody());

    try {

        if(1){
            $vendorSearchData = '';
            $db = getDB();

                $sql = "SELECT vendor_name,logo,phone_no FROM vender_list WHERE post_code LIKE :post_code";
                $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->bindParam("post_code", $pinCode, PDO::PARAM_STR);

            $stmt->execute();
            //echo "<pre>"; print_r($stmt); echo"</pre>";die;
            $vendorSearchData = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

            $db = null;

            if($vendorSearchData)
            echo '{"vendorSearchData": ' . json_encode($vendorSearchData) . '}';
            else
            echo '{"vendorSearchData": ""}';
        } else{
            echo '{"error":{"text":"No access"}}';  
        }

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
    }
}
```

Here is the file, where I call function to find data. If its `true`, then will navigate to another page, but on that page I get blank page:

```
findPlace(searchVal){
  this.authService.postData(this.vendorSearchPostData, "findPlace")
    .then((result) => {
      this.responseData = result;
      if (this.responseData.vendorSearchData) {
        this.dataSet = this.responseData.vendorSearchData;
        this.navCtrl.push(SearchResultPage, { data: searchVal});
      } else {
        let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
          message: "No data Found",
          duration: 2000
        });
        toast.present();
      }
    }, (err) => {

    });
  }
```

How display the search result on another page?

Comment: Please give me any suggestion for this.

Comment: Pass your data, store them in provider, store them in local storage... A lots of possibilities

Comment: i have tried but it shows the result on same page. I want it on another page